# Issue in laravel 5.5 task scheduling with cron job, command handle function not called

Tags: command, scheduled-tasks, laravel-5.5, laravel-artisan

```
**this is Kernel.php**
namespace App\Console;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{    
    protected $commands = [
        '\App\Console\Commands\SendNotificationLoginTrack'
    ];    
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {

        Log::info("from schedule before");
        $schedule->command('SendNotification:LoginTrack')
                 ->everyMinute();
        Log::info("from schedule after");
    }
    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

**This SendNotificationLoginTrack.php**
Issue in laravel 5.5  task scheduling with cron job,  command handle function not called.

if I called handle from the construct, it works fine.
But not handle function called automatically.

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;
use App\Mail\LoginTrackMail;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Mail;
class SendNotificationLoginTrack extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'SendNotification:LoginTrack';
    protected $description = 'Send Notification for Login Track';
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
         Log::info("hi from send __construct");
        //$this->handle();
    }
    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info("hi from send notification handle");
        Mail::to('xxxx@gmail.com')->send(new LoginTrackMail());
    }
}
```